# How to get same color for arrow shaft and arrow head with 3d quiver

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

The program below plots 3d arrows. I set the color for arrows depending on elevation (z coordinate).

WHAT WORKS: Arrow shafts get the correct color

PROBLEM: Arrow heads (whole or part) get a different color. Ugly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # noqa: F401 unused import
import matplotlib.cm as cm

n = 5
n3 = n*n*n
u, v, w = np.arange(n3), np.arange(n3), np.arange(n3)  # Positions
x, y, z = np.arange(n3), np.arange(n3), np.arange(n3)  # Vector components
colors = [(0, 0, 255)]*n3
mid = n/2
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            ii = i*n*n + j*n + k
            u[ii], v[ii], w[ii] = -(j-mid), i-mid, 0   # Whorl
            x[ii], y[ii], z[ii] = i, j, k
            colors[ii] = (1, 0, 0)
            if abs(k-(n-1)/2) < 1.1: colors[ii] = (0, 1, 0)
            if abs(k-(n-1)/2) < 0.1: colors[ii] = (0, 0, 1)

figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.gca(projection='3d')  # gca = get/create current axes

q = axes.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, color=colors, length = 0.5, normalize=True)
plt.show()  # Finally display the plot
```

Output:
[image: Output from the code above]

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is you didn't specify the color of the arrowheads, so matplotlib is cycling through your `colors` variable to color the arrowheads.

After your for loop, use the code below instead to fix the color of the arrowheads. Each vector is composed of 3 elements: a line for the body fo the vector plus two lines for the arrowhead. So if you have `n` vectors, you'll need to provide `n*3` colors to specify the colors properly.

Let's say you're plotting 2 vectors. Here's how the colors for the vector elements should be sorted in the array of colors: line1col, line2col, l1arrow1col, l1arrow2col, l2arrow1col, l2arrow2col, l3arrow1col, l3arrow2col.

```
# fix arrowhead colors
cs = colors[:]
for c in colors:
    cs.append(c)
    cs.append(c)

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 13))
axes = figure.gca(projection="3d")  # gca = get/create current axes
q = axes.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, color=cs, length=0.5, normalize=True)
plt.show()  # Finally display the plot
```

Here's a simpler example with 3 vectors that illustrates how to color the vectors.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.quiver(
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [-3, 0, 0],
    [-4, 4, -1],
    [-2, 2, 1],
    color=plt.cm.viridis(
        [200, 50, 100, 200, 200, 50, 50, 100, 100]
    ),  # line1, line2, line3, l1arrow1, l1arrow2, l2arrow1, l2arrow2, l3arrow1, l3arrow2
    arrow_length_ratio=0.3,
)
ax.set(ylim=(-5, 5), xlim=(-5, 5), zlim=(-5, 5))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65387776/11107541)'s correct, but for me, it only worked after I added the same colors list `cs`, to the edgecolor variable; that is: `ax.quiver(...., color=cs, edgecolor=cs)`

Comment: the previous answer is good but for me it only worked after I included the edgecolor variable as i explained